# Finding rates lower than averaged rates for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find districts that have crime rates lower than the averaged crime rate calculated for each table. I am supposed to do this for three different tables and each table will need to have its own unique averaged crime rate. This is how I did it, but I was wondering if there is not a better way? Would writing this as a stored procedure or function be better (not sure how I would though)? How else can this be done?

T1, T2, T3 respectively, are states for this example. I am looking at districts in three different states and I want averaged crime rates for each state. Then I want to print out the districts that fall below those averages. I would also like away to identify which union result set the results are coming from.

```
SELECT district, population
FROM T1
WHERE (crime/Population) < (SELECT AVG(crime/population) From T1) 
UNION ALL
SELECT district, population
FROM T2
WHERE (crime/Population) < (SELECT AVG(crime/population) From T2)
UNION ALL
SELECT district, population
FROM T3
WHERE AND (crime/Population) < (SELECT AVG(crime/population) From T3)
```

Comment: What's T1? What's T2? What's T3? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: T1, T2, T3 are states.

Comment: Seriously consider amending your schema. You need 1 table, not 50!

Answer (score 0):

solution simple you can add column to result (crime/Population) per table (T1,T2,T2) AND create table to result AVG(crime/population)